# How can I diff two files and get what is different in the second one as an output

Tags: css, merge, diff, comparison

What's easiest way to diff two files, check what is different in the second one and get it as output? I'm comparing two css files, and rest is the same only colors are different.

PS: I also want to keep the scope they are in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that you are after:
`diff -u f1 f2 > fpatch ; patch -i fpatch -o f2diff`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do this in Windows, the command `fc` might do what you want. Something like `fc firstfile.xxx secondfile.xxx > output.txt` the `>` will create the file output.txt and if you run the command again it will clear everything that was there and start the file over.  Two `>>` will append to the end of the file.  If they are in different locations and the path has spaces you will have to do it like this `fc "first folder\first file.xxx" "second folder\second file" >> "some other folder\output.txt"`  the command in Linux is simply `diff` but I don't know the syntax for that, here is a link to the  [syntax](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff)

Comment: Your redirection is not quite right... Using double `>>` will cause the output to be appended to an existing file. If no file exists, one will be created. A single `>` will cause a new file to be created to receive the output. If one already exists, it will be overwritten. These behaviors generally hold for both Unix and Windows.

Comment: Yup, totally swapped those, will edit, lol i write these i batch files at least monthly and still didnt catch that